# How to get complete localized datetime format in MVC application

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, asp.net-mvc, date

I am having Utc time and I need to convert it to client/Browser Datetime and display it based on Current Culture

For example, I had a UTC time as "**2021-01-14 00:00:00.0000000**" and Converting to ClientLocalTime as

```
TimeZoneInfo.ConvertTimeFromUtc(dateTime, clientTimeZoneInfo); // output 2021-01-14 05:30:00.0000000
```

and converting DateTime based on CurrentCulture as below:

```
dateTime.ToString("f", CultureInfo.CurrentCulture);
```

I am getting exact output for the locales "ro, en-US,en-NZ,de-DE, en-AU"

```
Thursday, January 14, 2021 5:30 AM
```

but I am not getting Day for these locales "en-CA,fr-CA" and gets output as

```
14 janvier 2021 05 h 30
```

but I want it as

```
jeudi 14 janvier 2021 05 h 30 // including (jeudi) Day of the week
```

Could someone help me with this?

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/custom-date-and-time-format-strings

Comment: It's rarely a good idea to allow a library or computer program to select a format based on "culture information" (e.g. review the vast array of formats defined for any particular culture at the [CLDR](http://cldr.unicode.org), which is the suggested basis for ECMAScript *toLocaleString* methods). It's much better to allow the user to select the format they want since even within a particular language or variant different people have different preferences.